# Access any key at anytime in C

Tags: c

How would could I set a key that would access any function at anytime, like for example I have a simple code here and anytime I am working or in the program I could exit with the ESC key rather just optioning it after all those lines, making it like shortcut keys...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
void main(){
int a,b,c,opt;
START:
clrscr();
printf("Enter Num A: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter Num B: ");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("Enter Num C: ");
scanf("%d",&c);
printf("Do it Again? ESC to Exit");
opt=getch();
if(opt==27) exit(0);
else goto START;
}
```

EDIT:
Is there any technique to command it like

```
while(inp!=27)
do{
...
}
```

So that the code would run and for example would exit if I pressed ESC key at anytime?

Comment: goto statements are generally a bad idea

Comment: conio.h is also generally a bad idea...

Comment: Please use loops instead of jumps!

Comment: I just use it to focus on accessing keys at anytime, I made my example a loop once but a simple one would be clearer, still thanks for advices

Comment: @rekize: `goto` is fine when used properly, just like any other construct.

Comment: Can there be any simpler code to return that up instead of goto? By the way, the question is not about the goto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the platform you are working on.  On windows (as an example) you would need to add a handler for the keyboard event message.  Then when that message is sent to your window you would have code to perform the shutdown.

Many development platforms make this easier for you by hiding the messages behind an event model.

Prior to windows you needed to hook into the interrupt stack (using a command called "TSR" for terminate and stay resident) of the keyboard driver.  Then when a keyboard event was called your code could run.

Comment: Does C Language have no feature or just a formula to do it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. C has to be able to work on systems that don't even have keyboards.

Comment: @Daniel - The C Language has nothing to do with the platform it runs on.  It is designed as general purpose.  You want a high level language if you have an expectation of an event driven model with mouse events and keyboard events and the like.